# Ansible not able to find python module

Tags: python, pip, ansible

Using ansible to run docker swarm on multiple virtual machines.
The ansible is not able to find the python module `docker` on the remote machine, even though it has been installed.

Runs the playbook
`sudo ansible-playbook -i inv2.py /etc/ansible/playbook.yml`

Error message:

```
fatal: [10.212.137.216]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import docker or docker-py - No module named requests.exceptions. Try `pip install docker` or `pip install docker-py` (Python 2.6)"}
```

Module list:

```
ubuntu@donald0:~$ pip list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
...
cryptography (2.1.4)
docker (3.7.1)
docker-pycreds (0.4.0)
...
```

Comment: Find out python's version "python --version" and make sure the system meet the [Requirements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_swarm_module.html#requirements).

Comment: Manager machine: Python 2.7.11  
Node machine: Python 2.7.15rc1

Answer (score 12):

This error occurs because Ansible is searching for a different path of the python modules that you are using.

When you install Ansible using the [official package](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#latest-releases-via-apt-ubuntu), it uses Python 2.7, so when you run Ansible it will search for the python 2 modules.

There are some ways to solve this:

**- Adding the `ansible_python_interpreter` option setting your correct Python path:**

Like the following example:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3'
```

**- Reinstall the ansible using the pip3:**

Using the following commands:

```
sudo apt remove ansible
pip3 install ansible
```

I think that the second option is the best approach to avoid future errors.

Read more about Python 3 Support with Ansible: [Ansible - Python 3 Support](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/python_3_support.html).

Answer (score 0):

The following configurations work for me. It installs docker, python and docker-compose  latest version

```
---
- name: Checking docker on latest version
  apt: name=docker.io state=latest

- name: Checking python
  apt: name=python state=latest

- name: Checking docker-compose on latest version
  apt: name=docker-compose state=latest
```

Comment: This example does not use any docker* ansible modules and does not need any docker(-py) pip module installed

Comment: @Zeitounator: The docker module from ansible requires the python docker module to be installed on the managed machine. One way to achieve this is to install `python-docker` using an Ansible module before using the Ansible docker plugin. Although I don't see this answer actually installing `python-docker`.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I had this problem because the directories under `/usr/lib64/python2.7` were readable and executable for `root` only. After I ran a `chmod -R go+rX /usr/lib{,64}` the problem was gone. `root`'s `umask` was `077`, hence the problem.

Answer (score -2):

You need python interpreter in you hosts file- /etc/ansible/hosts

```
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

For example:

```
ubuntu@${ip} ansible_private_key_file=~/.ssh/${var.key_name}.pem ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

For playbook, you need the Python Module and python docker-compose. Working example would be:

```
tasks:
    - name: Install Docker
      apt:
        update_cache: yes
        name: docker.io
  
    - name: Install Docker-Compose
      apt:
        name: docker-compose
  
    - name: Install Python Module
      apt:
        name: python3-pip
  
    - name: Install Python Docker-Compose
      pip:
        name: docker-compose
```

Comment: None of the task in your example use any docker module from ansible. How is this actually going to solve OP problems related to needed docker modules installed in python ?

Comment: @Zeitounator: The docker module from ansible requires the python docker module to be installed on the managed machine. One way to achieve this is to install `python-docker` using an Ansible module before using the Ansible docker plugin. Although I don't see this answer actually installing `python-docker`.