# azure pipelines ansible task fails with following error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ansible

while running ansible on agent machine in azure devops getting following error

> "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (packaging) on
> fv-az151's Python /usr/bin/python2. Please read module documentation
> and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is
> installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please
> consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below workaround, how did it go?

Comment: I was able to run playbooks from azure pipelines after installing this 4 modules packaging, msrest, msrestazure, ansible[azure] using pip2 install command.  I tried to add ansible_python_interpretor command still faced the same issue. So after installing the required modules i was able to run playbooks.

Comment: That's great it was fixed by installing the missing libraries. You can post out your fix to the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run playbooks from azure pipelines in azure agent after installing this 4 missing libraries

packaging,
msrest,
msrestazure,
ansible[azure]

using pip install command.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicated, Ansible seemed like using the wrong Python interpreter, if the python library is installed. So that it looked for the python library in different path of the python modules.

The workaround to fix this is to set the `ansible_python_interpreter` option to the correct Python path you are using. See below screen to add **Additional parameters** the Ansible task: See [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-handle-python-not-having-a-python-interpreter-at-usr-bin-python-on-a-remote-machine) for more information.

[image]

You can also try installing the ansible using the pip3:

See below commands:

```
sudo apt remove ansible
pip3 install ansible
```

Check out this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373596/ansible-not-able-to-find-python-module) for more information.